# cmake thinks variable is a directory

Tags: cmake, trilinos

I'm trying to install the trilinos package using the suggested cmake route. I dont have any experience with cmake, but there's a sample bash script that I found. When I try to execute this script I get the error

CMake Error: The source directory "/home/USER/code/packages/trilinos_build/MPI_EXEC:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/pkg/mpiexec" does not exist.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.

I checked the cmake doc and I'm pretty sure the syntax is correct, what am I missing?

```
#!/bin/bash

# Set this to the root of your Trilinos source directory.
TRILINOS_PATH=../trilinos_source
TRILINOS_BUILD_PATH=./

#
# You can invoke this shell script with additional command-line
# arguments.  They will be passed directly to CMake.
#
EXTRA_ARGS=$@

#
# Each invocation of CMake caches the values of build options in a
# CMakeCache.txt file.  If you run CMake again without deleting the
# CMakeCache.txt file, CMake won't notice any build options that have
# changed, because it found their original values in the cache file.
# Deleting the CMakeCache.txt file before invoking CMake will insure
# that CMake learns about any build options you may have changed.
# Experience will teach you when you may omit this step.
#
rm -f CMakeCache.txt

#
# Enable all primary stable Trilinos packages.
#
cmake \
  -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:FILEPATH="${TRILINOS_BUILD_PATH}/mpi" \
  -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=RELEASE \
  -D Trilinos_ENABLE_TESTS:BOOL=OFF \
  -D Trilinos_ENABLE_ALL_PACKAGES:BOOL=OFF \
  -D TPL_ENABLE_MPI:BOOL=ON \
  -D MPI_EXEC:FILEPATH="/usr/bin/pkg/mpiexec" \


$EXTRA_ARGS \
$TRILINOS_PATH
```

Comment: I am unsure, but it seems that `$EXTRA_ARGS` and futher parameters are not passed to cmake: they are delimited from previous parameters by several lines, and '\' at the end of the line provides continuation only on the next line. BTW, you may debug invocation of `cmake` by directly calling it with appropriate parameters, instead of using the script.

Comment: That's all it was, too much white space. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problems with cmake, it is because of the white enters between the last line and $EXTRA_ARGS \ . just remove the empty lines and the error will go away.

so your file should be like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Set this to the root of your Trilinos source directory.
TRILINOS_PATH=../trilinos_source
TRILINOS_BUILD_PATH=./

#
# You can invoke this shell script with additional command-line
# arguments.  They will be passed directly to CMake.
#
EXTRA_ARGS=$@

#
# Each invocation of CMake caches the values of build options in a
# CMakeCache.txt file.  If you run CMake again without deleting the
# CMakeCache.txt file, CMake won't notice any build options that have
# changed, because it found their original values in the cache file.
# Deleting the CMakeCache.txt file before invoking CMake will insure
# that CMake learns about any build options you may have changed.
# Experience will teach you when you may omit this step.
#
rm -f CMakeCache.txt

#
# Enable all primary stable Trilinos packages.
#
cmake \
  -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:FILEPATH="${TRILINOS_BUILD_PATH}/mpi" \
  -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=RELEASE \
  -D Trilinos_ENABLE_TESTS:BOOL=OFF \
  -D Trilinos_ENABLE_ALL_PACKAGES:BOOL=OFF \
  -D TPL_ENABLE_MPI:BOOL=ON \
  -D MPI_EXEC:FILEPATH="/usr/bin/pkg/mpiexec" \
$EXTRA_ARGS \
$TRILINOS_PATH
```

Also if you comment any line by # between the -D options the same error will show. after cmake\ all lines must be continuous.

hope itll help!